# Getting Bad request error while making Ajax call to Restful web service

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest, jaxb

I am trying to convert json object to xml document by using the following java script code:

```
function createXML(oObjTree) {
function loadObjTree(oParentEl, oParentObj) {
    var vValue,
    oChild;
    if (oParentObj instanceof String || oParentObj instanceof Number || oParentObj instanceof Boolean) {
        oParentEl.appendChild(oNewDoc.createTextNode(oParentObj.toString()));
    } else if (oParentObj.constructor === Date) {
        oParentEl.appendChild(oNewDoc.createTextNode(oParentObj.toGMTString()));
    }
    for (var sName in oParentObj) {
        if (isFinite(sName)) {
            continue;
        }
        vValue = oParentObj[sName];
        if (sName === "keyValue") {
            if (vValue !== null && vValue !== true) {
                oParentEl.appendChild(oNewDoc.createTextNode(vValue.constructor === Date ? vValue.toGMTString() : String(vValue)));
            }
        } else if (sName === "keyAttributes") {
            for (var sAttrib in vValue) {
                oParentEl.setAttribute(sAttrib, vValue[sAttrib]);
            }
        } else if (sName.charAt(0) === "@") {
            oParentEl.setAttribute(sName.slice(1), vValue);
        } else if (vValue.constructor === Array) {
            for (var nItem = 0; nItem < vValue.length; nItem++) {
                oChild = oNewDoc.createElement(sName);
                loadObjTree(oChild, vValue[nItem]);
                oParentEl.appendChild(oChild);
            }
        } else {
            oChild = oNewDoc.createElement(sName);
            if (vValue instanceof Object) {
                loadObjTree(oChild, vValue);
            } else if (vValue !== null && vValue !== true) {
                oChild.appendChild(oNewDoc.createTextNode(vValue.toString()));
            }
            oParentEl.appendChild(oChild);
        }
    }
}
const oNewDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
loadObjTree(oNewDoc, oObjTree);
return oNewDoc;
```

};
Now, I want to send the converted xml document to a restful web service using Ajax call from java script 
My ajax call is as follows:

```
     var lookupReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    var xmlDoc= createXML(lookupJson);
//make the ajax call to hit the web service   
lookupReq.send(xmlDoc);
```

My web service is as below:

```
@Path("/ImageServlet")

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})

public class ImageViewerServlet {



    @POST
    @Path("/lookup")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
    public Response getObjectId(GAIssuesLookupArg gaArg)
    {
        System.out.println("gaArgs : "+gaArg);
        return null;
    }

}
```

At the web service end, I am using JAXB for marshaling and unmarshaling.
But, I am getting Bad Request Error when I try to hit the web service by using the above mentioned ajax call. Can any one please tell me where I am doing the mistake and correct my code?
Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some indentation to your code? It's unreadable at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is there any option available in stackoverflow to add indention to the code? Could you please let me know if it is available?

Comment: No there is not. It's your job to properly indent your code. IDEs or something can help you with that, but not SO

Comment: Thanks. I have formatted the code now.